# How to convert a set of pandas dataframe columns to a list of dictionaries and save it into a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` :

```
   col1 col2 col3
0     1    a    W
1     1    b    X
2     2    c    Y
3     2    d    Z
```

I need to convert it into something like this, combining based on column 1 values:

```
   col1 col2 col3                    dict_col
0     1    a    W  [{'col2': 'a', 'col3': 'W'}, {'col2': 'b', 'col3': 'X'}]
0     2    c    Y  [{'col2': 'c', 'col3': 'Y'}, {'col2': 'd', 'col3': 'Z'}]
```

This is what i tried doing:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'col1': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'col3': ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

cols_to_use = ['col2','col3']

df['dict_col'] = df[cols_to_use].apply(
    lambda x: {'col2': x['col2'], 'col3': x['col3']},
    axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Do you know how to use `groupby`?

Comment: how to use `groupby` on this same line where i have used `apply`?

Comment: Well, you don't need to use it on the same line, but I suppose you could use `.assign`... Anyway, I'm just asking if you know how to use groupby at all. Cause if you don't, you should learn, but if you do, I'd want to see what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
g = df.groupby('col1')

df1 = g.apply(lambda x: x.drop(columns='col1').to_dict('records')).rename('dict_col')
out = pd.concat([g.first(), df1], axis=1).reset_index()
```

You can also do as alternative:

```
g = df.drop(columns='col1').groupby(df['col1'])

df1 = g.apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).rename('dict_col')
out = pd.concat([g.first(), df1], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   col1 col2 col3                                           dict_col
0     1    a    W  [{'col2': 'a', 'col3': 'W'}, {'col2': 'b', 'co...
1     2    c    Y  [{'col2': 'c', 'col3': 'Y'}, {'col2': 'd', 'co...
```

Comment: why are you using `x.drop`

Comment: Because `x` contains the col1 column and you don't want it in the dict, right? I updated my answer with an alternative. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby and then apply your function:

```py
def group_rows(sub_df):
    dict_col = []
    for i, row in sub_df.iterrows():
        dict_col.append(dict(row))
    return pd.Series({
            "col2": dict_col[0]["col2"],
            "col3": dict_col[0]["col3"],
            "dict_col": dict_col
            })
df.groupby("col1").apply(group_rows)
```

this will give you

```py
     col2 col3                                                                        dict_col
col1                                                                                          
1       a    W  [{'col1': 1, 'col2': 'a', 'col3': 'W'}, {'col1': 1, 'col2': 'b', 'col3': 'X'}]
2       c    Y  [{'col1': 2, 'col2': 'c', 'col3': 'Y'}, {'col1': 2, 'col2': 'd', 'col3': 'Z'}]
```